# Passing Event from Parent to Child Element (Polymer)

Tags: javascript, polymer, listener, event-bubbling

I am trying to have a parent element call a function from it's child.  In the parent's script I have:

```
_handleFunction: function() {
    console.log("Button Pressed!");
    this.fire('send-update');
}
```

And then in it's child

```
listeners: {
    'send-update': '_update'
},

_update: function() {
    this.$$('#element').innerHTML = 0;
}
```

But the child is not firing.

I have successfully passed a function up the chain using the design pattern.  Is it possible to pass back down using the same pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to invoke _update() function of your child element is to call it directly from the parents _handleFunction():

```
this.$.child._update();
```

where the child element has to have an HTML id of 'child'.